# Installing phalcon fatal error on OS X

Tags: phalcon

I do as stated in the documentation

> git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
>
> cd cphalcon/build
>
> sudo ./install

But I get error

```
    /private/tmp/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:108409:10: fatal error: 
    'libintl.h' file not found
    include <libintl.h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use the Linux/Solaris build instructions, which may not work on a BSD-based OS such as OS X.

According to [this page](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html) you should use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) or MacPorts to build/install phalcon on OS X:

```
sudo brew install php55-phalcon
```